# Mysql: mixed writing directions / get first character in case of

Tags: mysql, utf-8, arabic

My MySQL-Table has content in mixed alphabets and writing directions. I want to get the first letter of each line for Alphabetic order.

```
SELECT 
    term,
    left(term, 1)
FROM
    terms
```

results in:

```
'H مشبك ملتوي ذو شكل', 'H'
'م'       , 'مكعّب فسيفساء'
'H Word',              'H'
```

As you can see in case of terms which are either in arabic or in latin script *left* takes the first letter correctly, which is the most left or, in case of arabic, most right one. In case of a mixed term it gives the preference to the latin part and reads from left to right, while I want the opposite and get the most right character. (I can not tka the most right character, because in pure arabic and pure latin terms i would get the last character).

Therefore the expected result should be

```
'H مشبك ملتوي ذو شكل'
-> 'م'
'م'       , 'مكعّب فسيفساء'
'H Word',              'H'
```

I think there might be a trick to solve this, but maybe some had this problem before and knows some :)

Any Ideas? Thank you in advance!

Edit: Create testdata like this:

```
drop table if exists terms;
create table terms (
  term text
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3981 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into terms (term) values ('H مشبك ملتوي ذو شكل');
insert into terms (term) values ('مكعّب فسيفساء');
insert into terms (term) values ('H Word');
```

Comment: No. I gave it up and implemented another solution, a second field in the database, where you can insert a different version of the term to be used for the alphabetic sort - that solved another problem, that some of the terms started which special characters or arabic articles, as well. But Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. If the last character is not a latin one then it brings the first character for arabic (last one) otherwise it brings the first character for latin (first one). But note that you have to check your records if their last character is a numeric one.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e25f8/1)

```
SELECT term, IF(TRIM(term) NOT RLIKE '[A-Z]$', RIGHT(TRIM(term), 1), LEFT(TRIM(term), 1)) AS first_char
FROM terms;
```

Comment: I thought of something similar. Unfortunately RLIKE '^[A-Za-z]' or RLIKE '^[A-Z]' gives false for the pure arabic term and true for both, mixed and latin term.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Could you provide an\ SQL Fiddle with sample data?

Comment: I checked this on my localhost and it works properly.

Comment: SQLFiddle does not work for some reason. I pasted the code to create in the question. And your solution unfortunately does not work. In the first row, the mixed Script the H is NOT the first letter (think of it like the Arabian translation for Patient Z or such), but the last. Compared with a simple left(term, 0) your query results in the right letter for pure latin, the wrong (the last) for pure arabic and the wrong for mixed script.

Comment: Hm, I think that I misunderstood what you want. Can you edit your question providing the expected results?

Comment: That one selects the last arabic character in case of pure arabic or mixed alphabet, not the first.

Comment: I added expected results in Question

Comment: I thought that the most right one character in an arab word is considered to be the first one.

Comment: Yes, thats true. And the most right character in both arabic terms is م

Comment: It looks a bit different attached to a string. Your Query gives me  'ل'
'ء'
'H'

Comment: For some reason SELECT RIGHT(term, 1) FROM terms; gives ل for first row.

Comment: If I change your query to IF(tema RLIKE '[A-Za-z]'
            AND tema RLIKE '[^A-Za-z]$',
        RIGHT(tema, 1),
        LEFT(tema, 1)) as first_char it detects the mixed script term correctly and gives the right result for both pure terms.  But the Problem, that is doesn't select the H but the ل remains.

Comment: I checked for another word and it works fine: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a176a1/1 I really don't know what is happening as I don't speak arab.

Answer (score 0):

The Query you wrote working fine with me `left (term, 1)`
You do not have problem with it
The problem as I expected with the data you inserting,
I mean that:
your text `'H مشبك ملتوي ذو شكل'` already has the `H` char at the begining.
But the right string that you want must be like this: `'مشبك ملتوي ذو شكل H'`

Comment: As far as I am informed (without speaking arabic myself) the latin letter H is the last of the term, and was therefore inserted on the most left position of the term.

Comment: Try this to know what I am talking about `SELECT term, left(term, 3) FROM terms`

Comment: This `'H مشبك ملتوي ذو شكل'` is different from this `'مشبك ملتوي ذو شكل H'`, The last one is what you want.
Arabic written from right to left but in database saves as other languages